# how can I get the label where in the ItemTemplate with code behind C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label where in the Itemtemplate ,I want to get the value of the label but
just can't find control with the label, please somebody help me? thank you

aspx code:

`<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="工號" SortExpression="BS_ID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBSID" runat="server"
                                Text='<%# Eval("BS_ID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Textbox ID="tbBS_ID_edit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BS_ID") %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="BS_ID_tb"  Text="SK" MaxLength="7" runat="server" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>`
code

1. This is what I var

`//string lb_BS_ID = ((Label)GridView1.FindControl("lblBSID")).Text;
            //this._userID = lb_BS_ID;`

2. and I also try

`//string lb_BS_ID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblBSID")).Text;
            //this._userID = lb_BS_ID;`

3. Also

`//string lb_BS_ID =((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0]FindControl("lblBSID")).Text;
            //this._userID = lb_BS_ID;`

but those are not work for me please help me><

Answer (score 0):

instead of this: 
`string lb_BS_ID = ((Label)GridView1.FindControl("lblBSID")).Text;`

Try this. :

```
 Lable label = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblBSID");

 string value = label.Text;
```

Note : If you just need to find the value of the label in first row then use Rows[0] and so on instead of e.RowIndex.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Would you mind  answer a question to me? when start I var a private string _userID , After I insert the data into the database by textbox, _userID value become null, is it normal?

Comment: if it's normal how can i store some value like _userID after insert into database?@@

Comment: You are writing this code inside a gridview event right.?

Comment: no, this is inside a function when i edit the data in gridview

Comment: so you want to get the label's value from first row in gridview.? because this label is in every row. which row's label do you want.?

Comment: Do u Want to See What i Write XD? I'm a newbie for c# and i think what i write is like a fool hahaha

Comment: actually i 'm not sure is it the first row in this case, But I think it should be the first row

Comment: well! we all do stupid things in the beginning but with time we all improve so dont worry. (Label)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblBSID"); for the label in first row and (Label)GridView1.Rows[1].FindControl("lblBSID"); for the label in the second row and it goes on like this.

Comment: I just try this `Label lb_BS_ID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblBSID");
            this._userID = lb_BS_ID.Text;`

Comment: in my case first i have a query gridview for top 1 record at page_load the record is unvisable and then there have some footer row for input some value insert into database and query again to get what i type in the textbox
last there a edit delete for me to edit the record and i can't get the value of the label when I onclick the edit linkbutton

Comment: yeah i have try it already but can't find what i insert into the database when i onclick the edit before

Comment: I think It would be really great for you to look into these basic tutorials to get going with gridview and CRUD(Create,Update,Delete,Insert) Operations. Because its very important to get hold of a few basics. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-Delete-using-Single-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet.aspx http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/009464/make-edit-update-and-delete-operation-in-gridview-in-asp-net/ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/851092/ASP-NET-GridView-CRUD-Operations

Answer (score 0):

for updating the record use "OnRowUpdating" event of gridview; 
while using your code 1,2 and 3 make sure that your grid is binded to some data.

> you can not access any cntrol until your grid is binded to some data

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
            {
                int trackingno = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
                Label trackingno = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("yourLabelControlID");
//perform your update function
    }
```

for other operations you can use "OnRowDataBound"

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

                DropDownList ddeditpickuprider = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("yourDropdownControlID");
}
```